# Wordpress shortcode does not work when its wrapped in HTML

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, shortcode

I have create Wordpress pages that contain HTML elements like `<div>` and `<ul>` e.g.

```
<div id="main" class="large-12 medium-12 columns clearfix" role="main">
  <h2 class="press-list-header">Articles</h2>
    <ul class="press-list">

    </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to place short codes inside these HTML elements like this:

```
<div id="main" class="large-12 medium-12 columns clearfix" role="main">
  <h2 class="press-list-header">Articles</h2>
    <ul class="press-list">
[picture image="http://example.com/image1.jpg" thumbnail="http://example.com/image1-thumbnail.jpg"]
[picture image="http://example.com/image2.jpg" thumbnail="http://example.com/image2-thumbnail.jpg"]
[picture image="http://example.com/image3.jpg" thumbnail="http://example.com/image3-thumbnail.jpg"]
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I do this, the short codes just show up as regular text on the rendered page. If I just place the short codes outside of the HTML elements then they function properly rendering the expected content onto the page.

How can I get my short codes to render their content wrapped within HTML elements?

### UPDATE

I should have been more descriptive. I want to make it easy for my client to just drop in a short code in the TinyMCE editor for pages and posts. I do not want them having to deal with php or html code. They will not have access to those `.php` template files anyways since they aren't developers. I have gotten the short codes to work fine for just posts but not pages. I believe the reason for this is the fact that I am using a template called `custom-page.php` for all my pages which looks like:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Custom */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

  <div id="content">        
    <div id="inner-content" class="row clearfix">

      <?php the_post(); global $post; echo $post->post_content; ?>

    </div> <!-- end #inner-content -->
  </div> <!-- end #content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have determined that the problem lies in the line

```
<?php the_post(); global $post; echo $post->post_content; ?>
```

For some reason it is just rendering the short code text. It is not allowing the short codes to run and render the expected content. How can I rewrite this line to make short codes execute properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`do_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode):

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[shortcode]"); ?>
```

So in your template, it will look as such:

```
<div id="main" class="large-12 medium-12 columns clearfix" role="main">
  <h2 class="press-list-header">Articles</h2>
    <ul class="press-list">
<?php echo do_shortcode("[picture image=\"http://example.com/image1.jpg\" thumbnail=\"http://example.com/image1-thumbnail.jpg\"]"); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode("[picture image=\"http://example.com/image2.jpg\" thumbnail=\"http://example.com/image2-thumbnail.jpg\"]"); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode("[picture image=\"http://example.com/image3.jpg\" thumbnail=\"http://example.com/image3-thumbnail.jpg\"]"); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Adding to your **UPDATE**, the `do_shortcode` function is still the way to go:

```
<?php the_post(); global $post; echo do_shortcode($post->post_content); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I was not clear. I have edited my post with Update1 to further explain my problem in better detail. I hope you will be able to help. Thanks.

Comment: You can use the function `do_shortcode` everywhere, so you can do the following in your custom page: `<?php do_shortcode( $post->post_content) ?>`

Answer (score 0):

you need to do like this

```
<?php 
echo do_shortcode("[picture image='http://example.com/image1.jpg' thumbnail='http://example.com/image1-thumbnail.jpg']"); 
?>
```

Comment: Hey sorry I wasn't clear. I edited my question to be more clear. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php echo do_shortcode('<div id="main" class="large-12 medium-12 columns clearfix"   role="main">
 <h2 class="press-list-header">Articles</h2>
 <ul class="press-list">
 [picture image="http://example.com/image1.jpg" thumbnail="http://example.com/image1-thumbnail.jpg"]
 [picture image="http://example.com/image2.jpg" thumbnail="http://example.com/image2-thumbnail.jpg"]
 [picture image="http://example.com/image3.jpg" thumbnail="http://example.com/image3-thumbnail.jpg"]
 </ul>
</div>');
```

Comment: Thanks but I wasn't clear enough. I edited my question. What do you think?